# How to install PHP webserver on Intel Galileo Gen2

Tags: php, linux, webserver, intel, intel-galileo

How to install PHP webserver on Intel Galileo Gen2? I have the original Linux distribution on microSD and I installed the AlexT repositories.

Comment: Complete guess. `opkg install modphp`. That's the only php package I could see in the repo.

Comment: @JonStirling I know. But when i try to start the apache server, it gives segmentation fault error.